# Testing web site on a chinese network

Tags: javascript, web

I have received reports form a client that our web site is having problems when running in China.
The code is installed on an Apache server in China and is being viewed be users in China.
I am running the exact same code and not having the problem here (in the UK) and no other clients have reported the issue (all over the world). The error appears to be related to Javascript. I have been given RDP access to a machine in China and can see the error, but due to speed restrictions and access issues I cannot install any developer tools to debug the issue.

Is there a way of being able to access the offending site from my machine spoofing a Chinese IP address?

I guess this is the opposite of what people in China do to get round the great firewall of china.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try to debug the site via public proxy that reside in China.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess the issue from what your said. if your javascript loaded some js file from twitter, facebook sites which were blocked in china and the loading is in a synchronous way, such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="blocked.site/a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="userful.js"></script>
```

your userful.js will not be loaded.

To debug this, just view the web console in Chrome,IE,Opera, no additional software required.

To fix this, modify js loading in a non-blocking way or make a modified version for china clients.

Comment: Or just host `a.js` elsewhere...